# Directory Tree Iterator "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct"

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with the above error. It seems whnever I add a folder to the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` I get this error message.

Currently it works fine with this path: `C:\wamp642\www\\refit\code\username_2` but when I add a folder like so: `C:\wamp642\www\\refit\code\username_2\files`

it throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message
 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\wamp642\www\refit\code\username_2iles,C:\wamp642\www\refit\code\username_2iles): 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 
(code: 123)' in C:\wamp642\www\refit\code\username_2\files\curzon_1.php on line 13
```

My code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "asd123", "slick");
if($mysqli->connect_error)
{
    exit('Error db');
}
$username = 'username_2';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8mb4");
$_SESSION['mysqli'] = $mysqli;

$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("C:\wamp642\www\\refit\code\username_2", RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)); 
foreach($it as $path => $branch)
{
    if(is_dir($path))
    {
        echo "".$path. "<br>";
        if(!file_exists("files"))
        {
            mkdir("files");
        }
        //echo $it.'<br>';
        $schism = pathinfo($path);
        echo "".$schism['basename']."<br>";
        $original_path = $path;
        $folder_name = $schism['basename'];
        if($schism['basename'] == "files")
        {
            echo '';
        }
        else
        {
            mkdir("files\\".$schism['basename']."");
        }
    }
    if(is_file($path))
    {
        echo "".$path."<br>";
        $schism = pathinfo($path);
        $media = basename($path).PHP_EOL;

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$username." (original_path, folder_name, media) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $original_path, $folder_name, $media);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

}

?>
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Why not use single quotes and forget about double slashes?

Comment: I didn't know lol. So you're meaning this line: `mkdir("files\\".$schism['basename']."");` to be like this: `mkdir('files\'.$schism['basename'].'');`

Comment: I'm thinking it has to do with the folder `file` being the folder that this php file is in. The code works with the path as just straight `__DIR__` so I wonder if it's that. The problem is that when I try to get this php to iterate through `files\folder\` it doesn't work. Any ideas?